# Excel Row numbers from n worksheets to new excel or worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to copy and paste some specific row numbers from one excel workbook, but that Excel workbook contains many sheets.

I'm trying to copy Row number 3,4 8,9 and 10 from each workbook, we have 100 excel sheet like this:

[image]

But in my final result, I want this as follows

```
OrganizationName   ProductName    Average_Rating    NUmerofSoldService CurrentUserCount

Apple               iphone          3.43                15                 79

Apple               ipad            4.28                 20                100

Samsung             Galazy          3.182                50                20

and so.. on
```

Could you please suggest to me how to copy and paste into either a new sheet or workbook?

Comment: Are you referring to copying/pasting programmatically?

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to do that either by VBA or Excel code

Comment: Is your sheet named "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"... ? Hint, you can try indirect() function.

Comment: yes, it is sheet1, sheet2, and... so on..

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  Change the range to suit your needs.

```
Sub Basic_Example_3()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceCcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim Cnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    Cnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next
                Set sourceRange = mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("A3:C10")

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all rows then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Rows.Count >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceCcount = sourceRange.Columns.Count

                    If Cnum + SourceCcount >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough columns in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in the first row
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(1, Cnum). _
                                    Resize(, .Columns.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.cells(2, Cnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        Cnum = Cnum + SourceCcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub
```

See the link below for more info.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm